# Error: Extender controls may not be registered before PreRender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to add Ajax Controls to my *.aspx pages.

I just added

```
<asp:CalendarExtender TargetControlID="UserName" runat="server">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

And getting the error. Any solution?

Please don't tell me to read the similar questions on stackoverflow.com. None worked for me.

Comment: Can you show us more pertinent code, such as the register clauses per example ?

Comment: register clauses?
Sorry I am newbie...

Comment: <%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajax" %> ?

Comment: This is I have in my page where I am trying...
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

Comment: Seems ok to me, where did you placed the ToolkitScriptManager ? ("<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="toolkit1" runat="server"></ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>")

Comment: What else necessary to make Ajax tags work in *aspx pages?

Comment: I have added this too.  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager> But :(

Comment: Please, post your entire code...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46061/discussion-between-user3110335-and-cubitouch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the chat, you should never put the :

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Inside a `LayoutTemplate`, as in the `Login` control for you case, see http://forums.asp.net/post/5101565.aspx.