# Printing an aspx file in Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have used the following code to print an HTML DIV Contents & it works fine, but when I am using an Ajax Control in an Aspx page then it gives me an error message, i.e:

> "Extender control 'CalendarExtender2' is not a registered extender
>   control. Extender controls must be registered using
>   RegisterExtenderControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().
>   Parameter name: extenderControl"

**Here is my C# code**

```
protected void BtnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

    Page pg = new Page();
    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
    HtmlForm frm = new HtmlForm();
    pg.EnableEventValidation = false;
    pg.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    frm.Controls.Add(divContent);
    pg.DesignerInitialize();
    pg.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
    string strHTML = stringWrite.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTML);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>window.print();</script>");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

**Here is my Aspx code**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Masters/TSAMaster.master"      AutoEventWireup="true"
EnableEventValidation="false" Theme="skinFiles" CodeFile="AdminHome.aspx.cs"
Inherits="Masters_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidateDate() {
        isValidDate = ValidateDate();
        if (!isValidDate) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

    }
    function ValidateDate() {
        var Fdate = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFDate').value;
        var Tdate = document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtTDate').value;

        var todaysDate = formatDate(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        var isValidDate = true;
        var flag;

        if (trim(Fdate) != 0 || trim(Tdate) != 0) {

            if (!isDate(Fdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) {
                alert("Please select valid From Date enter into (dd/MM/yyyy) format");
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFDate').focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (!isDate(Tdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) {
                alert("Please select valid To Date enter into (dd/MM/yyyy) format ");
                document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtFDate').focus();
                return false;
            }

            if (((compareDates(Fdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy', Tdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy')) == 1)) {
                alert("To date cannot be less than From Date ");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    function trim(str) {
        return str.replace(/^[\s]+/, '').replace(/[\s]+$/, '').replace(/[\s]{2,}/, ' ');
    }
</script>

<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
    EnableScriptLocalization="true" ID="ScriptManager1" />
<center>
    <div class="divContainPage" id="divContent" runat="server">
        <table id="tblHead" runat="server">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="DueDate Report" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Verdana"
                        Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#C80000"></asp:Label>
                    &nbsp;<br />
                    <br />
                    <table id="tbl1" runat="server" style="width: 823px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Select Payment Mode:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPayMode" runat="server" CssClass="DropDown" Width="85px">
                                    <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Cash</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem>Cheque</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                From Date:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFDate" runat="server" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalendar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.png"
                                    TabIndex="1" />
                                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtFDate"
                                    Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupPosition="BottomRight" PopupButtonID="imgCalendar" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                To Date:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTDate" runat="server" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgCalendar1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/calendar.png"
                                    TabIndex="2" />
                                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtTDate"
                                    Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupPosition="BottomRight" PopupButtonID="imgCalendar1" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btnGo_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateDate();" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" Width="47px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table style="width: 600px" runat="server" id="tblone">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:GridView ID="grdStudentInfo" runat="server" SkinID="Professional" DataKeyNames="StudentID"
                                    Width="800px" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84"
                                    BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2"
                                    OnSorting="grdStudentInfo_sorting" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="grdStudentInfo_PageIndexChanging"
                                    OnRowCommand="grdStudent_RowCommand">
                                    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="FirstandLastName" SortExpression="FirstandLastName">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="100px" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="100px" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Amount Due" DataField="FirstInstallmentFee" SortExpression="FirstInstallmentFee">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="100px" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="100px" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Payment Mode" DataField="FirstInsMode" SortExpression="FirstInsMode">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="100px" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="100px" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Bank Name" DataField="FirstBankName" SortExpression="FirstBankName">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="200px" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="200px" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cheque Number" DataField="FirstChequeNumber" SortExpression="FirstChequeNumber">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="200px" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="200px" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Due Date" DataField="FirstInstallmentDate" SortExpression="FirstInstallmentDate">
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="200px" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="left" Width="200px" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" CommandName="editStudent" Text="Edit"
                                                    CommandArgument='<%#Eval("StudentID")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px" />
                                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="200px" />
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
                                    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id="tbl3" runat="server">
                        <tr style="height: 30px;">
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnExport2PDF" runat="server" Text="Export To PDF" OnClick="btnExport2PDF_Click" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnExport2XLS" runat="server" Text="Export To XLS" OnClick="btnExport2XLS_Click" />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hidSort" runat="server" Value="1" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</center>
```

If I use `frm.Controls.Add(tblOne)` instead of `frm.Controls.Add(divContent)` then it works fine because `tblone` doesn't have an Ajax Control. But `divContent` has both the table as well as Ajax Controls, and it throws the above exception. I have tried many options like overriding `OnInit` and `OnPreRender` but doesn't work for me.

Comment: what is the code on your ASPX page itself?

Comment: Off-topic, but you can't have 2 functions with the same name in javascript. Actually, maybe you can, but it's unpredictable which one will be called.

Comment: @Nate Kerkhofs sir if the problem is bcz of functions then it will give a error while using a <tblone>, i have renamed both the functions names but still problem persist.

Comment: I did not say your problem was because of your function names, I just gave some advice related to your code that was off-topic to the question. That's why I did not post it as an answer, because it wouldn't solve your problem. It could have prevented a potential future problem with your javascript though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion i was little bit confused sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have resolved this problem by using JavaScript code & it works better for me, i would like to thanks for all who gives their valuable time & feedback.
The code is here :

```
<script>
    function Panel1() {
        var panel = document.getElementById("<%=printablediv.ClientID %>");
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>newTable</title>');

        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        setTimeout(function() {
            printWindow.print();

            printWindow.close();
        }, 1000);
        return false;

    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the placement of ToolkitScriptManager in your code. See if this resolves your problem:
[Error: Extender controls may not be registered before PreRender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347764/error-extender-controls-may-not-be-registered-before-prerender)

Comment: Just a hunch but can you try registering this event on the control's onInit event? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353474(v=vs.110).aspx